# How to enable Turbine stream using Cloud foundry Rabbit MQ service

Tags: rabbitmq, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix, turbine

I am trying to integrate Hystrix CircuitBreaker in my sample application.I have two apps, one behaving as server other as client. CircuitBreaker is working fine as well i can see Hystrix.stream form client.

Now i am trying out multiple clients in one DashBoard using Turbine stream.

On server side i have added 2 dependencies as below :

```
spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream
spring-cloud-starter-stream.rabbit
```

and annotation @EnableTurbineStream on application.

On client side i have added below dependencies:

```
spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-stream
spring-cloud-starter-stream.rabbit
```

Both application deployed in Pivotal Cloud Foundry and binded to Rabbit Mq service for PCF.

On Client deployment i see below Exception :

```
java.io.IOException :null
Caused by : com.rabbitmq.client.ShutDownSignalException :  channel error     :protocol method : #method<channel.close><reply-code=406, reply-test=PRECONDITION-FAILED - equivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'spring.cloud.hystrix.stream' in vhost '' : receieved 'topic' but current is 'Direct', class-id=40, methid-id=10>
```

On hiting Turbine server, i m getting

```
data : {type : ping}


Management port on turbine server is set to -1.
```

Is any MQ configurtion required on client and sever to push Hystrix stream in Rabbit MQ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The client side error is telling you that you are trying to declare an exchange that already exists, but with a type that conflicts. You could fix it by changing the exchange name or by just deleting the old one. Or simply delete the service and re-create it in Cloud Foundry,

Comment: Thank you @Dave for response. I tried with recreating  the service and it worked.

Comment: Now i m trying to use Cloud foundry Circuit breaker service following git hub samples. https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/traveler. i have deployed agency and company apps in CF and agency tied to circuit breaker service from CF. i can see Hystrix stream on agency app. but no data coming up in circuit breaker service dashboard from CF. i can see same error coming up in agency logs. Can you please help to resolve this, am i missing any dependency?

Comment: And one more question is Circuit breaker service from CF is tied to Service discovery. is it possible to use Circuit breaker service from CF without using service discovery?